# Why nav element doesn't work with @media screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, nav

I was seeking for solutions; i found similar problems with its solutions but it still no working.

The body and landing text, has updated okay when i run it and i check it out, but `.nav-list` no. I tried changing code, changing normal-screen .`nav-list`...But nothing.
I'm also going to share you a image in order to clear it better:

[image]

So... The idea is that this element is showed like a column. Any solution? Thanks!

```css
.top-nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100vh;
    z-index: 50;
    /*background-color: #9b4646; */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    transition: all 650ms cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);
}

.nav-list{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background: url(images/sitebg2.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .landing-text h1{
        font-size: 15rem;
    }

    .landing-text h6{
        font-size: 1.7rem;
    }

    .nav-list{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="menu-toggler">
            <div class="bar half start"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar half end"></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link"> Home </a>
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link"> About </a>
                    <a href="#services" class="nav-link"> Services </a>
                    <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link"> Portfolio </a>
                    <!--<a href="#experience" class="nav-link"> Experience </a> -->
                    <a href="#others" class="nav-link"> Other</a>
                    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link"> Contact </a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </nav>
        <div class="my-logo">
            <h1>
                <!--<img src="images/my propio logotipo.jpg">-->
            </h1>
        </div>

    </header>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML as well (Preferably in a snippet so we can see it in action)

Comment: Done, i uploaded the header section. I could put more if you want to.

Comment: There is a feature on Stack Overflow, accessed via a button with `<>` in it on the editor toolbar (called [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)), in which you can add HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and that can be run here on Stack Overflow so that we can see the code in action and get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: I have add your code to a StackSnippet. Please edit the snippet so that it clearly shows the problem that you describe when run.

Comment: If you are expecting the `a` elements to be stacked when the screen width is less than 768px, your flex code should be on the `li`. Not the `ul`.

Comment: @Turnip ah, yes, i fixed it. The problem was i had all the `a` elements in just one `li` section, so i have to put one by one inside a distinct `li` sections. Thanks so much!